# Android app published in "Closed testing track" yet not showing up in google play

Tags: android, google-play-console

I've made an update to an existing app which is running in the production track. Lets call this version 1.0.. This one is, since its production, installed on users devices. Now I've made a release of version 1.1 in a "closed track", in which I've included my own email address. On my device where I've logged in with the same email address no update has shown up yet a few hours after i got an email telling me that the update is live. The Google Play console also shows "Available to selected testers".

Am i missing something?

Comment: Copy the link of your app in testers tab of your release track and navigate to the link. Does it show the new version of your app?

Comment: Just tried that. It shows the new changelog, but version is still shown as 1.0. On my Android 10 tablet, the 1.1 update had actually arrived, but on another older tablet (same account) it is still only version 1.0. Its pretty wierd

Comment: is your problem soved? I am also facing the same issue.